# Get size of available UI space in pixels

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have the following `Pivot` control in my WP7 app.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <controls:Pivot Title="foo" >
        <controls:PivotItem Header="Item1">
            <Grid>
                <Image x:Name="imgItem1" Source="{Binding Path=Item1ImageUri}" Stretch="None" />
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>

        <!-- ... more PivotItems -->

    </controls:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

I want the `imgItem1` image to fill the available space on the page.
In my code behind I have overridden the `OnNavigatedTo` method where I request an image from a web service. I can give size parameters in the URI to the webservice. I want to find the available size for the image in pixels and send those values to the web service.

I thought `(int)imgItem1.ActualHeight` and `(int)imgItem1.ActualWidth` would be good to look at, but they are 0 until an image has been assigned, and then they are the height and width of the image.

How do I find the max/available size of the image to load?

Comment: Have you tried removing Stretch="None" from the image? Just a guess...

Comment: @Anvaka, that does not change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangleMeasure" Fill="Transparent" />
    <Image x:Name="imgItem1" Source="{Binding Path=Item1ImageUri}" Stretch="None" />  
</Grid>
```

Use the ActualHeight and ActualWidth of the rectangle to determine the size values to include in your URL.

Comment: Nice hack, you just need put it in the page `Load` event instead of the `OnNavigatedTo` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also reference the pages ActualHeight and ActualWidth from the Loaded event.

e.g.

```
       private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(this.ActualHeight);
       }
```

Note that either approach will produce 768 rather than 800 if the SystemTray is enabled.

```
       shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
```

Comment: This does not take into account the Pivot control that surrounds the image.

Comment: Not sure what else you've got there, but I just tried this in a default Pivot app and got the same results as above. Arguably, it's not a big deal for you if you have a working solution.. just a curiosity now.

Comment: `this.ActualHeight=696.0` and `rectangleMeasure.ActualHeight=551.0`, The `Pivot` control has some Header text and spacing around the `PivotItem`.